# Многоклассовая классификация

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, классификация

Я делаю классификатор, есть 50+ классов, у них есть 100 + массивов по 100+ элементов

Подробнее: Существует dataset массивов c номерами классами к которым они относятся

```
dataset = {
"Класс 1": [[16, 18, 11, 18], [14, 11, 14, 16], [13, 10, 11, 17]],
"Класс 2": [[38, 38, 34, 37], [30, 38, 39, 34], [30, 32, 38, 38]],
"Класс 3": [[57, 50, 51, 51], [58, 50, 50, 56], [50, 58, 56, 58]]
}
```

Мы подаем 1 массив на вход

```
input_data = [[21, 11, 25, 16]]
```

На выходе я хочу получить процент совпадения моего входного массива с каждым классом, например:

```
Совпадения Input_data:
с классом 1 на - 85%
с классом 2 на - 50%
с классом 3 на - 10%
```

Существует условие, что массивы из dataset похожи друг на друга, например `i[0][0]` + - похож на `i[1][0]` и на `i[2][0]`

Логика, как я понимаю, должна быть такая, я делаю стандартное отклонение, но вот что дальше не знаю

```
for key, values in dataset.items():
    x1 = values[0][0], values[1][0], values[2][0]
    x2 = values[0][1], values[1][1], values[2][1]
    x3 = values[0][2], values[1][2], values[2][2]
    x4 = values[0][3], values[1][3], values[2][3]
    
    print(np.std(x1, axis=0))
    print(np.std(x2, axis=0))
    print(np.std(x3, axis=0))
    print(np.std(x4, axis=0))
```

Я попробовал байесовский классификатор, но это не очень помогает

Comment: А что за данные то по своей природе? Как-то странновато выглядит это всё. Ну и стандартное отклонение - это не про то вообще. Смотрите тогда уж лучше корреляцию. Но вообще "степень похожести" - штука неоднозначная. Не зная природу данных можно только гадать о принципах этой похожести.

Comment: @CrazyElf Суть происхождения данных следующая. Есть конвейер на котором едут детали, с помощью камеры я получаю по 2 координаты x, y, z детали и получаю на основе них длину одной стороны в см, все детали всегда повёрнута одинаково. Получаю массив расстояний каждой стороны вот так:  

input_data = np.array([np.linalg.norm(np.array(point_cloud[i[0]]) - np.array(point_cloud[i[1]])) for i in lines])  - расстояния в сантиметрах каждой стороны детали

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, такая первоначальная прикидка, не векторизованная, на чистом питоне, вообще без библиотек. Просто считаем что-то типа *среднеквадратичного отклонения* и берём от него корень, чтобы размерность сохранить.

```
dataset = {
"Класс 1": [[16, 18, 11, 18], [14, 11, 14, 16], [13, 10, 11, 17]],
"Класс 2": [[38, 38, 34, 37], [30, 38, 39, 34], [30, 32, 38, 38]],
"Класс 3": [[57, 50, 51, 51], [58, 50, 50, 56], [50, 58, 56, 58]]
}

input_data = [[21, 11, 25, 16]]

for i in input_data:
    print(i)
    for k in dataset:
        print(k, sum(sum((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(row,i))/len(dataset[k]) for row in dataset[k])**0.5)
```

Вывод:

```
[21, 11, 25, 16]
Класс 1 15.340577998671801
Класс 2 36.71965867669978
Класс 3 72.1295131459146
```

Наименьшее отклонение тут от `Класс 1` получилось.

**Обновил формулу**, теперь результат не зависит от того, сколькими образцами представлен каждый класс. В предыдущей версии результат мог быть искажённым, если число образцов по классам различалось.

Comment: Выглядит уже похожее на правду, пойду пробовать, если что отпишу)

Comment: @Leonid Там по-хорошему надо на число списков ещё делить до взятия корня, я потом формулу доделаю, как время будет )  Но это будет существенно только в том случае, если по разным классам будет разное число списков

Comment: @Leonid Сделал обновление

Comment: а я вот ещё что подумал. Может стоит сначала сделать 1 массив со средними значениями, 
`for key, values in dataset.items():
    pre_dataset[key].append(list(np.mean(values, axis=0)))`
Дальше считаем квадратичное, но делим ещё на N-1. `(((a - b) ** 2) / (len(row) - 1)) ** 0.5`
Ну и выводим вот так `[print(key, sum(values) / len(values)) for key, values in res.items()]`. Но ты похоже уже так всё и сделал)

Comment: @Leonid Если у вас все размеры в массиве пропорциональны классу, то да, можно вообще посчитать заранее `mean` и сравнивать `mean` образца с `mean` классов. Если нет выбросов и классы разделимы по `mean`, то всё ещё проще, да. Причём, сделать это всё через `Numpy` и работать будет моментально. Просто подсчёт `RMSE` (среднеквадратичного отклонения) как бы более универсальный способ, часто применяющийся на практике.

Comment: да, в программе массив на вход содержит 128 элементов, и в датасете всегда будут массивы по 128 элементов в каждом

Comment: Ну, это хорошо, но я не про кол-во элементов, а про то, что все размеры у вас примерно одинаковые для одного класса, а не так, что один размер маленький, другой большой и т.д. внутри одного класса

Comment: да я про них, немного не так выразился, в общем ваш обновлённый вариант идеально подходит, спасибо большое!